# Replace Android library project by JAR library?

Tags: android, jar, library-project

In my project, there are many library project (more than 10). It takes long time to build. So I want to replace some of these library projects by JAR libraries.

According to this question: [How to Convert an Android Library Project to an External JAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973822/how-to-convert-an-android-library-project-to-an-external-jar)

As CommonsWare's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/7973950/190309)

> If your library is purely Java code, with no resources, you can create
>   a JAR out of the .class files, just as you would with regular Java.

But when using NineOldAndroids library (https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids) from Jake Wharton,

> This library is presented as a .jar file which you can include in the libs/ folder of your application.

It means although there are many resources in NineOldAndroids, I can use it as a JAR library instead.

With ADT 17, for every library project, there is a JAR library in lib_project/bin/lib_project.jar which automatically generated each time library project is built.

Can I use this JAR as an alternative for library project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It means although there are many resources in NineOldAndroids

There are precisely zero resources in NineOldAndroids. You can tell this by [looking at the project](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/tree/master/library) and seeing that there is no `res/` directory.

> With ADT 17, for every library project, there is a JAR library in lib_project/bin/lib_project.jar which automatically generated each time library project is built.
>
> Can I use this JAR as an alternative for library project?

Not at this time. That JAR still depends on the library project itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried and documented this issue in [how-to-consume-reusable-gui-element-widget-with-resources-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721860/how-to-consume-reusable-gui-element-widget-with-resources-in-android) and i didn-t succeed with adt-17. but maybe i did something wrong.

CommonsWare-s answer to my qestion says

```
 > Eventually (which now appears like it will be the R18 version of tools or later), the 
 > tools should support packaging reusable components in a JAR, with resources, in 
 > such a manner that you can add them to a host project and the resources will 
 > be blended in automatically. Right now, that's not an option.
```

Comment: Yeah, and R18 (and R19) have come and gone without this feature yet being added. I have given up predicting when they will ship this capability. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the jar generated for a library project, you'll see there is no resource in it. It is only used for the Java classes.