# can i provide a project contents as jar files to another projects?

Tags: android, jar, libraries

Hi i have the project developed in eclipse environment is working fine, and i want to use that project as resource or add as jar file to another project.if possible can please let me know how to do this one. will help lot for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it via Android Library project.

Refer this [LINK](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html).
Describes how to set up a project as a library project. Quoted from its content

================= quoted =================== Next, set the project's Properties to indicate that it is a library project:

```
1) In the Package Explorer, right-click the library project and select Properties.

2) In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.

3) Select the "is Library" checkbox and click Apply.

4)  Click OK to close the Properties window.
```

=============== unquoted =============================

So, you open your project properties and "unselect" "is Library" checkbox and click Apply to make your project a normal Android project (not a library project).

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can as @Agarwal described.

however the adt-tools are not ready to do it yet

My last failed try was adt-tools version R17 documented at [how-to-consume-reusable-gui-element-widget-with-resources-in-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9721860/how-to-consume-reusable-gui-element-widget-with-resources-in-android)

According to user @CommonsWare R18 and R19 still cannot do it (see [comment in replace-android-library-project-by-jar-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10176519/replace-android-library-project-by-jar-library/10176740#10176740) )