# How to convert android library project to .jar file with all classes and resources?

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

I need to convert android project to .jar file with all classes and resources.can we have a option to do that ? I tried by converting to android library project and then to jar file.It always shows null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

If your library is purely Java code, with no resources, you can create a JAR out of the .class files, just as you would with regular Java:

```
1. Right click the project.
2. Export --> Java --> JAR file.
3. Tick the files to include and name the jar, click "Next".
```

For step by step details incase of java see [this](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~scottm/cs307/handouts/Eclipse%20Help/jarInEclipse.htm).
For android see this [ans](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7973822/3879470).

```
You cannot export the library project to a self-contained JAR file, as you would do for
a true library. Instead, you must compile the library indirectly, by referencing
the library in the dependent application and building that application.
```

**EDIT:** 

 For using drawables of the library see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6241429/3879470).

Comment: My library contains more drawables and xml layouts.can we create jar and use it on other project ?

Comment: cannot create jar for android, see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/7973822/3879470, however if you make the project as library you can use its classes like you do for any other java project.